# Deploy Tunneling techniques

Tags: ipv6, tunneling

I understand about different Tunneling techniques (6to4, ISATAP and Teredo).

However, most of papers and books are absent of how to deploy these techniques. For example, if I have a dual-stack router (ipv4/6), how can I install/enable 6to4 or ISATAP or Teredo on that Router (linux) OS?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Teredo you can simply install miredo-client and start it. This will provide you with an IPv6 address that is globally reachable. However, this will not provide you with a /64 subnet, so you can't use this to route. It works well for single devices, though.

If you want to enable your home network with IPv6, best is probably if you go with 6in4 (not 6to4). If you have a fixed IPv4 address, you could head to the Hurricane Electric website and get yourself a /64. If your external IPv4 address is changing, try to go with Sixxs and the AICCU client. If you then install radvd, the Router Advertisement Daemon, on your router and configure it to announce your /64 prefix to your home network, you will have IPv6 connectivity on all your machines. Remember to set up your firewall correctly, as these addresses would be reachable from the outside.